# Capture AppFabric issues into SCOM

Tags: monitoring, workflow-foundation-4, appfabric

After installing app fabric management module for use with systems center operations management (SCOM), it only monitors the app-fabric product itself and not the applications we have deployed to it, that are hosted inside app-fabric.

For example we need go get notified when there is a failure in a WF instance or/and the instance get suspended or when a throttle value is reached for number of errors in WCF calls etc.

How can we set up this  monitoring task in SCOM?

Comment: So these are the results you're getting from the AppFabric Management Pack in SCOM?